# Home page set in GPO; users still seeing "Enhanced Security Configuration is not enabled" warning

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, internet-explorer

When users open up IE on my terminal server, they are seeing the IE ESC warning instead of their home page:

[image: Enhanced Security Configuration is not enabled]

Here's some of the relevant facts:

- OS is Windows Server 2008 R2
- Home page is specified in the GPO `(http://intranet)`
- If user hits the Home button, it indeed takes them to the intranet page, so I know the GPO is working
- Loopback processing is enabled in Replace mode (no profile leakage from the user's OU)
- The message only appears the first time they use IE after their user profile gets built. Subsequent logons take them straight to the home page.
- The RDS is a six-server farm, and they see the message once for each server. Therefore, from the user's perspective, it appears to happen randomly.

How do I suppress this warning for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  I set a group policy registry preference under the User Configuration to delete the following registry value:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Delete the value "First Home Page"

Answer (score 0):

We don't use terminal services, so I'm not sure if this will work, but have you tried configuring `Prevent running First Run wizard`?  It is located at `Computer Configuration | Policies | Administrative Templates | Windows Components/Internet Explorer`.  Set this to go directly to home page.

Additionally, try setting  the `Specify default behavior for a new tab` to home page as well.

You may also be able to force this through the use of a preference, located at `User Configuration | Preferences | Windows Settings | Internet Settings`.

Comment: The GPO where the home page is specified is actually a comprehensive set of IE policies that includes the settings you mentioned, specified in the user configuration (so it can be set to not apply to admins). A `gpresult` confirms that they're being applied.  The preference idea is a good one though. I just don't know what key/value to set.